# In "Solo: A Star Wars Story" - has the identity of this character been officially confirmed?

Tags: star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, we saw

> a red Dathomirian with a red lightsaber.

Everyone is calling him

> Darth Maul.

Do we know for sure that he really is

> Darth Maul

?

> I know that he survived after Obi-Wan sliced him into half, but there's no reason why another red Dathomirian can't exist. He didn't look like the original Maul and his lightsaber design was also different.

Do you have proper citation to prove that he is

> Darth Maul

?

Comment: Don't have a proper citation for you, so I'm not going to add this as an answer, but there's a lot of buzz about that character having his own spinoff movie, so there's that I guess.

Comment: The lightsaber design is a match for the one Maul uses in the two animated series, The Clone Wars, and Rebels

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker he also has the classic Mail head, if they recreated a character that looked that similar and named him something else that would’ve been incredibly confusing. There’s a reason Maul’s “brother” is yellow and not red...

Comment: I mean, he's listed as Maul in the end credits. Isn't that proof enough?

Comment: The body is the same actor from *The Phantom Menace* and the voice is the same as *The Clone Wars*

Comment: “He didn't look like the original Maul” — Ray Park played him, so it’s difficult to work out how they could have made him look more like “the original Maul”.

Comment: Also the music in that scene plays “Duel of the Fates” which is strongly associated with Darth Maul.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes**

Director Ron Howard confirmed the character's identity:

> I will say that was scripted and there was a lot of uncertainty as to who that character would be.  So it was sort of initially written in a rather generic way.  It just sort of said “Boss”.  And I thought when I came in, I assumed they knew who it was and they were just keeping it under wraps.  And they didn’t.  But Maul was listed as one of the candidates.  And I lobbied hard for that.  I thought that made a lot of sense to me.  I found that character to be really effective.  And I knew for a fact, without asking directly and giving anything away, my son Reed who just turned 31, who’s a dedicated Star Wars fan, he’s a golfer.  He’s not in the business.  Dedicated Star Wars fan.  I just whispered that possibility and he just thought that would be incredibly cool.  And so for that generation, I thought, well that was gonna be a pretty interesting idea.

http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2018/05/ron-howard-talks-about-how-big-reveal.html

As have screenwriters Jon and Lawrence Kasdan:

> Jon was a particular champion of Darth Maul. We knew that Dryden was not the top of this ladder at all, and we wanted it to be someone really powerful. But Jon was the one who said, 'It's got to be Darth Maul.

http://www.starwarsunderworld.com/2018/05/the-kasdans-discuss-big-reveal-in-solo.html

Comment: And on top of that, Maul is rather recognizable as Ray Park - who apparently even attended the premiere, to the surprise of many: https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/star-wars-how-solo-premiere-spoiled-darth-maul-cameo-1115480